# Import the google analytics report data(Including custom dimentions & Metrics) to sql server

Tags: sql-server, google-analytics, ssis

here is my requirement : Import the google analytics report data(Including custom dimentions & Metrics) to sql server.
For this, I created the ssis package and also integrated the "SSIS Google Analytics source".(Ref : http://analyticssource.codeplex.com/)
In Google Analytics source, I got the preview for some dimensions(`ga:UserType, ga:city` etc) and metrics(`ga:pagetittle, ga:users` etc) only.

But if I select any metric starts with "%" like "% New Sessions" or "Avg" like "Avg. Time on Page" it shows the error as follows:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'dataType' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataType
   at System.Data.DataColumn..ctor(String columnName, Type dataType, String expr, MappingType type)
   at System.Data.DataColumn..ctor(String columnName, Type dataType)
   at SSISComponents.DataTypes.GaDataToDataTable(GaData googleData)
   at SSISComponents.FrmGoogleAnalyticsSource.btnQuery_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e).
```

I selected the Dimentions and Metrics as per the report that was generated in analytics.google.com.

How to resolve this error and How can i get all the reports data(Dimensions and Metrics those are shown in analytics.google.com including custom dimensions also) using SSIS.